# what can be removed when minimizing hook_views_default_views in a module?

Tags: views, 6, hooks

I'm working on a new drupal 6.x module (currently in sandbox awaiting review - http://drupal.org/sandbox/sdague/1072704) which exports it's data via views.  When I implemented hook_views_default_views() I just used the export functionality on views for a few basic views to get things started.

That works, but those are both very verbose, and don't implement any i18n. Is there a standard way of trimming down the default values in those views so this becomes a bit more sane and maintainable?

Answer (score 1):

I find that the [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features) does a better job exporting the view. It adds an array of translatable strings. I haven't compared the verboseness of the views exported, but most they are probably the same. Most of the verboseness comes from defining fields. Some options might not be strictly needed - compared to the UI, but when importing/exporting things, it's better to be a bit over verbose, than to rely on default values.

With some practice, you can learn to spot the important stuff and ignore the rest.